# Custom metric in multi-output Keras model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, vgg-net

I'm working on a custom multi-digit number recognition problem. I only have 1 and 2 digit numbers. I am using a VGG16 model with two heads for each digit individually to avoid having 100 classes.

THe model looks like this:

```
input_shape = (256,96,3)
base_model = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape = input_shape)
xo = base_model.output
x = base_model.input
flat = Flatten(name = 'flat')(xo)
h1 = Dense(1024, activation='relu', name = 'first_hidden_layer')(flat)
d1 = Dropout(0.5, name = 'first_hidden_dropout')(h1)
h2 = Dense(1024, activation='relu', name = 'second_hidden_layer')(d1)
d2 = Dropout(0.5, name = 'second_hidden_dropout')(h2)

o_digit1 = Dense(11, activation='softmax', name = 'digit1_classification')(d2)
o_digit2 = Dense(11, activation='softmax', name = 'digit2_classification')(d2)

model = Model(inputs = x, outputs = [o_digit1, o_digit2] )
opt = Adam(lr=0.0001)
model.compile(optimizer=opt, 
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics={'digit1_classification': 'accuracy', 
                             'digit2_classification': 'accuracy'},
              loss_weights = {'digit1_classification': 0.5, 
                             'digit2_classification': 0.5})
```

I would like to build a custom metric to pass to the model. Compile that calculates the actual number accuracy. Normally when you build your own metric function you pass `y_pred` and `y_true` to it. 
For example

```
def my_metric1(y_true,y_pred):    
    return calculations (y_true, y_pred)
```

I could use `my_metric1` to calculate whatever I want on each class individually, but what I want is for it to calculate actual full number accuracy. 
Something of this sort:

```
def my_metric2(y_pred1, y_true1, y_pred2, y_true2):
    return calculations2(y_pred1, y_true1, y_pred2, y_true2)
```

Here `y_pred1, y_true1, y_pred2, y_true2` are predictions and true values for each digit individually.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: would it be possible to have only one output (concatenation of the 2 previous ones) and define custom metrics/loss for it?

Comment: Hm.. That might be possible. I need to figure out how to do a custom loss, because I wouldn't be able to do a categorical_crossentropy because if I stock my two ouputs into one vector, it won't one-hot encoded anymore.

Comment: A custom loss is just like a custom metric except it has to be differentiable.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 2 digits as individual outputs, then you can create a custom loss function something like this -

```
import numpy as np

# Define custom loss
# Create a loss function that adds the MSE loss to the mean of all squared activations
def custom_loss(y_pred1, y_true1, y_pred2, y_true2):
    Loss = 0

    def loss1(y_true1,y_pred1):
        return np.square(np.subtract(y_true1,y_pred1)).mean()

    def loss2(y_true2,y_pred2):
        return np.square(np.subtract(y_true2,y_pred2)).mean()

    def finalloss(y_pred1, y_true1, y_pred2, y_true2):
        Loss = loss1(y_pred1, y_true1) + loss2(y_pred2, y_true2)
        if(y_pred1 == y_true1 and y_pred2 == y_true2):
           return(0)
        elif(y_pred1 == y_true1 and y_pred2 != y_true2):
            return(0.5 * Loss)
        elif(y_pred1 != y_true1 and y_pred2 == y_true2):
            return(0.5 * Loss)    
        else:
            return(Loss)

    return finalloss(y_pred1, y_true1, y_pred2, y_true2)

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=custom_loss, # Call the loss function 
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# train
model.fit(data, labels)
```

Better is to have just one output in the model for both the digit. Something like this Fully connected [1x1x2] layer. You can find multi digit detector article [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/build-a-multi-digit-detector-with-keras-and-opencv-b97e3cd3b37).